Are there any instances of the "Lights Out" puzzle only solvable with square-root-of-NOT gates?
TL/DR: Can we solve a classically unsolvable instance of "Lights Out" when the lightbulbs neighboring the switch that we flip see a $\sqrt X$ gate, instead of being fully negated? If so, would that be a borderline instance of quantum computational advantage?

I had recently asked a question on math.stackexchange about the "Lights Out" - a simple solitaire game played on an $m\times n$ grid of light bulbs and corresponding switches. Conventionally by flipping a switch at row $i$, column $j$, that bulb and the (von Neumann) neighboring bulbs are negated. When presented with such a grid with some bulbs on and the remaining bulbs off, the goal is to flip a sequence of switches to get all of the lights turned off.
Each switch effectively performs a "NOT" gate ($X$ gate) on all corresponding bulbs. In the math.SE question I had asked whether we get a reduction in the number of switches that need to be toggled, by using square-root-of-NOT gates in lieu of (or in addition to) the NOT gates used in the conventional puzzle.  I quickly realized that for $4\times 1$ or $8\times 1$ puzzles with periodic boundary conditions, indeed a conventional solution needs all switches to be flipped, while a "quantum" version that only applies $\sqrt{\text{NOT}}$ ($\sqrt X$ gate) to the two neighboring cells needs half-as-many toggles (every other cell on the chain is switched).
For example, let $|\psi\rangle=|11111111\rangle$, let $i=(j-1)\bmod 8$ and $k=(j+1)\bmod 8$, and let our (classical) switch act as $X_i X_j X_k$ while our quantum switch acts as $\sqrt X_i X_j \sqrt X_k$. Classically we'd need to apply all eight switches in order to turn the lights off to $|00000000\rangle$, while quantumly we only need to apply every other switch. So the answer to the math.SE question is "yes", at least a chain of eight cells with periodic boundary conditions can be solved faster when $\sqrt X$ is applied to neighboring cells.
But, depending on $m$ and $n$ and the periodicity of the boundary conditions (as well as the neighborhood that is toggled) some puzzles are classically unsolvable.  For example, from this website we can see that a $6\times 7$ puzzle with periodic boundary conditions and a von Neumann neighborhood of NOT gates is only solvable on $1/4$ of all instances:

So, are there any instances of Lights-Out that can only be solved when the von Neumann neighborhood uses $\sqrt X$ gates on at least some of the neighboring cells?
Is this another quasi-instance of "quantum advantage without entanglement", as there are no two-qubit entangling gates in the game, and it's only the superposition-inducing square-root-of-NOT gates from whence an advantage exists, if at all?

Are we thinking that you press a button on a site, and it implements, independently, root(not) gates on that site and its neighbours. Then, after a sequence of these, you measure all the sites to collapse onto light on/off states? I think it's pretty clear that there are combinations which can be created this way that cannot be created with the classical model. As for solving it, I guess that's going to depend on whether you accept a probabilistic solve...

@DaftWullie I intentionally left that a little vague because I didn’t want to limit the question too much but I’d say it’s ok to have the center site see a not while the neighbors see root(not), e.g. Also I was thinking starting with basis state $|0110110001\cdots 1\rangle$and ending at basis state $|00000\cdots 0\rangle$(or a superposition of the zeroes ket and at most maybe 3 other states so there’s a non-0 or no limiting chance of solving it).

Also, I guess the neighborhood doesn’t need to be von Neumann, and the gates don’t need to be the square root but could be some other third or fourth… root or otherwise, and the periodicity doesn’t need to be a torus/cylinder but a Klein bottle or Mobius strip, etc.

Presumably I should think of the system as a classical error correcting code. Then the codewords represent the different sets of positions that any classical strategy can always push me towards. If the smallest representative of each codeword has some maximum weight w, presumably I could succeed with a probability ~$1/2^w$. But maybe before we can answer a quantum question, we should consider a probabilistic classical system rather than a deterministic one...

A probabilistically classical system has no memory of whether the switch has been clicked before, right?
